# New Apple ID, Can't update previous apps on mac

Tags: macos, photos, apple-id

So I have a macbook pro and I recently made a new apple ID account due to a muck up with the old one the whole family was using.

I've changed everything on my mac to make sure that my apple ID account is the only one logged in and everything which is working fine, the only problem is, 2 original apps that come with the mac (iPhoto and iMovie) need to be upgraded but every time i try to upgrade them it asks for my old apple id which is disconnected so it won't let me update them.

I'm not great with technology so if you have any ideas to help please put every step and detail in.

Can I delete these original apps off my mac and re download them under my new account while saving all my photos?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options

You can either buy them again [they may not be eligible as free versions twice] or use the ID & password they were originally downloaded under.

It shouldn't matter if the old versions are there at the time.

Answer (score 1):

The steps for this are pretty simple - but each might need an article from apple with all the steps.

1. Set up time machine to back up all your data and apps - this frees you in case you make a mistake or skip a step.
2. Don't worry if you delete an app - it doesn't delete your photos and data - just the application that isn't personalized. Your settings and photos and things you personalize stay behind when an app is deleted
3. Confirm your new account works in the Mac App Store (buy some free app or re-download the apps in question). Lucky you these apps are now free so you don't have to buy them again with money - just time.
4. Open each app and verify the data upgrades.